# Signed cookies in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

I set a signed cookie like this:

```
cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_me] = [user.id, user.salt]
```

When reading the cookie:

```
cookies.signed[:remember_me]
```

I get:

```
14cc5d64cd84f96f8847726a6ed0e280235025379
```

What does this value mean? How could I get user's `id` back?

I use Rails 3.2.6.

Answer (score 2):

i think first of all u should do

```
 cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_me] = user.id
```

then only you can retreive it by

```
 cookies.signed[:remember_me]
```

although by signing it no one can decrypt the cookie at client side

Answer (score 0):

Simply use cookie[:remember_me]

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to assign the salt to the cookies...the hash is generated automatically by the signed function...
you can simply use

cookies[:remember_me] = user.id

Comment: I would like to store the salt so that, if user changes his password, the cookie would become invalid.